# How to store data from file.dat to a struct array

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

```
#define Capacity 1000
struct Book{
        char BookID[10];
        char Title[100];
        char Author[50];
        float Price;
        int YearOfRelease;
    } lstBook[Capacity];
FILE *infile;
    infile = fopen ("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\BookMan6\\BookMan.dat","rb");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
     fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening BookMan.dat\n\n");
      exit(1);
    }
```

I want to ask how to store data from file.dat(after writing to file from a struct array) to a new struct array of Book.please help!

Comment: You mean like `int itemsRead = fread(lstBook, sizeof(struct Book), Capacity, infile);`?

Comment: It works,thank you so much!!